# Result from mongodb is null, but if (!result) is not catching it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I always used `if (!result)` to catch when a result is null, but for some reason this is just not working here?!?

```
exports.getDiscount = function(req, callback) {

   var discountModel = require('../models/discountModel');
    var discountTable = mongoose.model('discountModel');
    discountTable.findOne (
        { _id: req.body.discount }
    ,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {callback( { error:true, err:new Error('findDiscount: ' + err) } )};

        console.log("data " + data)
        console.log("json: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        if (!data) {
           callback( { error:true, err:"NOT FOUND: " + req.body.discount + " was not found" } )
        }
        console.log("WHY ARE YOU NOT STOPPING?!?!")
        console.log("data " + data)
        console.log("json: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

        if (Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) > data.expires) {
           callback( { error:true, err:"EXPIRED: " + new Date(data.expires*1000).toDateString() + " " } )
        } 
       callback( { error:false, percent:data.percent } );
    });
}
```

And this is my console output

[image]

How come the callback at `if (!data) {` is not catching this null value?

Comment: Um, may *return* ?

Comment: @Jonasw yah, I thought the callback would be the same as a return, I guess not :-)

Comment: BTW. The answer your accepted in incorrect. Callback arguments are `callback(err,response)` (in generic terms meaning two arguments) the problem is you are only passing in a **single** argument, which is being interpreted as the `err` part. Your last call should be `callback(null,percent:data.percent);` So the `err` is considered `null` and the `response` is the actual data sent back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code is stopping execution after `if (!data) { ... }` from executing. (Or, for that matter, `if (err) { ... }`, etc. )

Most likely you just want to `return false;` or something after calling the `callback()` function

If you throw a `console.log()` inside that `if` block, it should show that the code is entering the block.

Comment: Ahhh you were right Justin!! - I thought the callback would be enough, but after I put return after each callback, then everything worked.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped :)